# Webpack 4 - copy font files to specific location

Tags: webpack, fonts

I have following config of Webpack, to copy glyphicon font files to my target location:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        'target/web-resources/resources/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot',
        'target/web-resources/resources/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg',
        'target/web-resources/resources/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf',
        'target/web-resources/resources/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff',
        'target/web-resources/resources/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
        filename: '[name]'
    }

};
```

After run of webpack the file is created, but with following content: https://pastebin.com/WbyMBQVz

What is wrong with my config that it doesn't use file as it is without content replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the glyphicon files as entries, which mean they become bundles and the contents of each file becomes the zero-th module in its bundle. So instead of seeing each file copied to the same directory you are creating a bundle for each glyphicon file that only includes reference via the public path to the copied file.

If all you need to do is copy files I suggest you use a task runner [like Gulp](https://coderwall.com/p/9uzttg/simple-gulp-copy-file-task), or use the [copy webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

---

Some background info:

The `file-loader` loader copies a file to the output directory defined in your webpack configuration, which in your case would is `path.resolve(__dirname, '.')`, for it to then be fetched by the client via the public path to your assets.

It does not include the contents of a file in the actual bundle produced by webpack.

As you can see in the config the glyphicon file is only referenced by name:

```
__webpack_require__.p + "glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot";
```

Where `__webpack_require__.p` is the public path, as defined on line 80 in your bundle:

```
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
```